# SQL - JAVA Apostrophe issue

Tags: java, sql

SQL - Java Apostrophe issue.

```
sb.append("and NOT (T1.COLUMNTYPEONE like 'BDP%')");
```

I get this error:

> token "BDP" was found following "nvalid column name '".  Expected tokens may include:  ",".. SQLCODE=-104, SQLSTATE=42601, DRIVER=4.7.112.

How should I be writing this code to avoid apostrophe issue , dont want to change to PS or anything.

```
sb.append("and NOT (T1.COLUMNTYPEONE like 'BDP%')");
```

Comment: The problem is in other code that you have not shown.

Comment: The _real_ problem is [SQL injections](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)

Comment: Most likely, you don't have a column called `COLUMNTYPEONE` in whatever `T1` references.  But you haven't really provided enough information for anyone to be sure of this.

Comment: Could it be that you have an unbalanced `'` earlier in your SQL statement? That would explain why `BDP` is recognized as a token.

Answer (score 0):

I think your syntax is ok. It would be nice if you details your database structure. This query example, as simple as it is, is correct, showing an adequate use of apostrophes:

```
String sql = "SELECT id, first, last, age FROM person" +
                   " WHERE first LIKE '%za%' ";
```

If there were a problem with the query string the exception thrown would be a String-related exception, well, I'm not really sure about the apostrophe special treatment with StringBuffer.

Answer (score 0):

As it thinks that BDP is a column name (though of course invalid), it seems that the apostrophes are unmatched in the entire SQL string. One may dump the SQL string with the exception. Appending string literals must also escape apostrophes in the string value.

BTW it could not hurt to insert a space `" and..."`.